# Subplot imshow and plot sharing same dimensions

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two subplots, an `ax1.imshow` and a `ax2.plot`. I want the `imshow` to retain its original aspect ratio, and I want the `plot` to have the same height as the `imshow`. In addition I want there to be no gap between the two subplots, meaning the two black borders should be right next to eachother or overlap.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax1.imshow(np.random.random((100,100)))
ax2.plot(np.random.random((100)))
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()

fig.tight_layout(pad=0.0)
fig.savefig("test.png")
```

Gives the result [image: Result of non-aligned imshow and plot]

I basically want the right subplot to have the same height (and be aligned) with the left subplot, and have no gap between the two subplots.

I can achieve this somewhat by adjusting `figsize`, however that can be very tedious. Especially if some other parts of the figure is changed, necessitating tweaking the `figsize` multiple times.

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(8,4))
```

[image: Result of aligned imshow and plot using figsize]

Answer (score 0):

While `subplot` usually does a very nice job positioning things automatically, you can use `axes` to position them manually when you need to. This solves the problem of the space between your plots. See the specification of `rect` [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axes).

The aspect ratio issue is trickier, and I'm sure there are approaches cleaner than this one. You can specify the aspect ratio of the plot (using the `aspect` keyword of the `axes` method) in terms of the aspect ratio of the image you are showing.

The snippet below illustrates both the use of `axes` and the use of `aspect`.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 100
yRange = 1.0
x = np.arange(N)
y = np.random.random((N))*yRange

imageX = 100
imageY = 150
image = np.random.random((imageY,imageX))

imageAspect = float(imageY)/float(imageX)

myDataAspect = float(N)/yRange * imageAspect

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.axes([0.05,0.05,0.45,0.9])
ax2 = plt.axes([0.5,0.05,0.45,0.9], adjustable='box', aspect=myDataAspect)
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()

ax1.imshow(image)
ax2.plot(x,y)

fig.savefig("test.png")

plt.show()
```

Comment: That works for imageX=100 and imageY=150, but if imageY goes above a certain value (for example 200) there will be a gap between the subplots. This seems to be caused by the aspect ratio "forcing" of ax2. 
One way to solve it would maybe be to access the position of the frame of ax1, and then setting the frame position for ax2?